# What's an efficient way to rank records within a group in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ranking

I have a table with potentially up to a few hundred thousand rows. Each row represents an application for funding within a census block, by a given applicant. If I have just a couple hundred rows, I can assign a rank to each application within its census block using this:

```
SELECT art1.CFA_Plus, art1.Census_Block_ID, 
    (SELECT count(*) + 1 
FROM AppReferenceTable art2 
WHERE art2.State_Cost_Per_Unit < art1.State_Cost_Per_Unit AND 
art2.Census_Block_ID = art1.Census_Block_ID) AS Rank_In_Block         
FROM AppReferenceTable AS art1;
```

This works fine to rank each application by unit cost within that census block. But it chokes on my test table, which has about 60,000 rows. Is there a better way? Or, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: When calculating live gets too much, you can store the results. Add a field in your AppReferenceTable  and create an UPDATE query that fills it with the rank. Schedule that to run every night. Unless not having the latest data immediately is a deal breaker, it will do the job.

Comment: Your sub-query is not optimisable for MS ACCESS, each record has to be re-calculated and this impacts its performance. Dealing with such large Dataset you should already have thought to move to a dedicated DBMS. MySQL is free and you can still use MS Access front-end and take use of all those fancy SQL operations.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - joining the table with itself does the trick.

```
SELECT art1.Census_Block_ID, art1.CFA_Plus, art1.State_Cost_Per_unit, COUNT(*)  As Rank
FROM appreferencetable as art1
LEFT JOIN appreferencetable as art2
ON  art1.Census_Block_ID = art2.Census_Block_ID AND  art2.State_Cost_Per_Unit <= art1.State_Cost_Per_unit
GROUP BY art1.Census_Block_ID, art1.CFA_Plus, art1.State_cost_per_unit
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you got it, but just in case others come across this, I've made a ranking system that designates a tie breaker if needed.  I also made a video for how to do this from scratch: 
[Microsoft Access - How to Create a Data Ranking Field in a Query (and Making a Tie Breaker System)](https://youtu.be/9wlme8NcBC8)

```
SELECT sub.employeeID, sub.dob, sub.rank
FROM (SELECT e1.dob, e1.ID, e1.employeeID, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM employees AS e2

WHERE (e2.dob < e1.dob) OR
      (e2.dob  = e1.dob AND e2.ID < e1.ID)
   ) + 1 AS rank
   FROM employees AS e1
   )  AS sub
ORDER BY sub.rank;
```